# Translate/convert date in other language to english in php

Tags: php, timestamp

I have a timestamp in Bangali language:

```
$myTime = "২০১৫-০৬-২২ ০৮:৩১:৫৩";
```

how can I convert it to English language in php like this...

```
$myTimeEng = "2015-06-22 08:31:53";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short example:

```
<?php
    $translate = array('০','১','২','৩','৪','৫','৬','৭','৮','৯'); // 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 in bengali
    $myTime = "২০১৫-০৬-২২ ০৮:৩১:৫৩";
    $myTime = str_replace($translate, array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), $myTime);

    echo $myTime;
?>
```